# Zebra scanner Interleaved 2 of 5 cannot read

Tags: android, kotlin, barcode-scanner, zebra-printers

I have Zebra TC510K and I am developing an app on it in Kotlin. I am using this EMDK com.symbol:emdk:9.1.1. I am trying to scan Interleaved 2of5 barcode but the scanner doesn´t response.

My code is show below. This is only place where I set decodeParams.i2of5.enabled = true. Other types of barcodes works properly. Do you have somebody some idea what should be wrong?

```
override fun onStatus(statusData: StatusData) {
        val state = statusData.state
        when (state){
            StatusData.ScannerStates.IDLE -> {
                statusString = statusData.friendlyName + " je zapnuty a ceka...."
                if (!scanner!!.isReadPending()) {
                    val scannerConfig = scanner!!.config
                    //Log.d("scanpr","Before${scannerConfig.decoderParams.i2of5.enabled.toString()}")
                    scannerConfig.decoderParams.i2of5.enabled = true
                    scannerConfig.decoderParams.code128.enabled = true
                    scannerConfig.decoderParams.code39.enabled = true
                    scannerConfig.decoderParams.code93.enabled = true
                    //Log.d("scanpr","After${scannerConfig.decoderParams.i2of5.enabled.toString()}")
                    //scanner!!.config(scannerConfig)
                    try {
                        scanner!!.read()
                    } catch (e: ScannerException) {
                        statusString = e.message.toString()
                        statusTextView!!.text = statusString
                    }
                }
            }
            StatusData.ScannerStates.WAITING -> {

            }
            StatusData.ScannerStates.SCANNING -> {

            }
            StatusData.ScannerStates.DISABLED -> {

            }
            StatusData.ScannerStates.ERROR -> {

            }
            else -> {

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post a picture of a printed barcode?  It is also possible that your scanner is not configured to scan i2of5.  Most scanners use special "programming" barcodes provided in the users manual to enable/disable what symbols they recognize.

Comment: Actually I tried DataWedge on the same device and it works and can read the code. It looks like I have to change code to use DataWedge intent application.

Comment: For example, if you just enable Interleaved 2 of 5, it may be a mode that also requires a check digit by default. If your library has an option to disable the Interleaved 2 of 5 check digit, try specifying that as well.

Comment: @jenik2205 Using DataWedge is recommended however the EMDK definitely does support I2of5, possibly as the above commenter says there are some additional attributes of I2of5 you need to set.  You can see what values DataWedge assigns these under your DataWedge Profile --> Barcode Input --> Configure Scanner Settings --> Decoders --> Interleaved 2of5

Comment: Thank you all, actually nothing works and I am trying to use DataWedge now. @DarrynCampbell thank you for your response. May I ask whether you could help me with it? My question is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70625523/using-datawedge-for-multiple-activities-on-zebra-barcode-scanner-doesnt-work-in

Comment: @jenik2205 apologies for the delayed response but I have been on holiday - I answered your question at that link.

Answer (score 0):

I forget to add one line to setDecoder functionality: scanner!!.config = scannerConfig. To set config of scanner.

```
                    if (!scanner!!.isReadPending()) {
                    val scannerConfig = scanner!!.config                    
                    scannerConfig.decoderParams.i2of5.enabled = true
                    scannerConfig.decoderParams.code128.enabled = true
                    scannerConfig.decoderParams.code39.enabled = true
                    scannerConfig.decoderParams.code93.enabled = true
                    scanner!!.config = scannerConfig                    
                    try {
                        scanner!!.read()
                    } catch (e: ScannerException) {
                        statusString = e.message.toString()
                        statusTextView!!.text = statusString
                    }
                }
```